How to get rid of new Spring Boot warning about DelegatingWsConfiguration is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors?
With Spring Boot 3.3.0 I get the following warning upon server startup:

10:13:20.610 WARN  [main] o.s.c.s.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker: Bean 'org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.DelegatingWsConfiguration$$SpringCGLIB$$0] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying). The currently created BeanPostProcessor [annotationActionEndpointMapping] is declared through a non-static factory method on that class; consider declaring it as static instead.

What's the recommended way to get rid of this warning ?
The issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/issues/1391#issuecomment-1939434373 was rejected claiming that it's a Spring Boot issue.

I've just commented on the issue. The problem needs to be fixed in Spring Web Services. I don't think there's anything you can do in your app to get rid of it.
